# How to programatically generate config forms in magento?

Tags: php, xml, magento, configuration, module

I have a payment gateway plugin, that serves as an all-in-one service for several gateways. I have these gateways standarized in classes that i've used for WooCommerce and Drupal, to process the payment process, and order generation.

These classes have some configuration fields that's different from one to the other.

In WP and Drupal, i've been able to generate the configuration forms with PHP dinamically (from PHP).

In Magento, the only good way of generating options nicely is through the system.xml file. This handles the saving process and the form generation nicely.

I've tried to Inherit from the Fieldset Block class, and use the frontend_model class to render the fields dinamically. But the fields generated doesn't work as expected.

This is because even if set the same parameters for a text field in the XML file and in the fieldset addField method, the field doesn't generate the same way (for example, i couldn't get the comment to show up when generating the field from PHP).

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way (and the only I know) is to do it via xml like any magento module. You can take exemple on system.xml of mage_catalog for exemple.

Comment: But i want to be able to dynamically generate these forms. XML files doesn't let me load these by some condition, or have other XML files to load extra fields or not.

Comment: @Matias Saggiorato: If that's a question what Magento supports, please contact the vendor of that software for your support options (there are a few). If you're talking about a programming problem, please provide a code-example with your question that matches the criterias for this Q&A website: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - also there is a Q&A dedicated to Magento itself if this is less a programming question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/